# Data Structure for efficient distribution

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have a train with N wagons. Each wagon `i` has `n_i` cells, while each cell has 6 seats.

Now suppose 0 < x <= 6 passengers entered wagon `i` of our train and want to sit in the same cell. I want to find the first appropriate cell which have enough free seats in worst case `O(log*n)`.

Initialisation of the system can take up to `O(n)`.

n=total number of cells in train.

I have tried to solve this problem with 6*(number of wagons) disjoint sets, however I'm having difficulties maintain such a complex solution.

PS: `log*n` is an Iterated logarithm.

Comment: In this particular case, you know already the waggon and n_i will be rather small (say < 10), I guess the best solution is a naive linear search.

Comment: This question is purely theoretical, thus you can't make such assumption.
Number of wagons and number of cells within a wagon can be an arbitrary large number.

Comment: Is the `N` relevant to your question? It seems to me that solving this for one wagon is identical to solving it for `N`, because your queries are for a specific wagon only, right?

Comment: Indeed, the original question is more complex so I omited few details.

Comment: What does "first appropriate cell" mean?

Comment: Do you want the "best fit" or the "first fit"?

Comment: first appropriate cell = cell with enough seats, obviously.

Comment: Why don't you use the cells as your primary object, keep them in 7 lists/arrays. Array 0-> Empty Cells... Array 6 -> 6 seats taken. Tag all the other information to the cells (wagon index etc.). If you need a cell with room for 3 you find it behind that index. Then you transfer the cell to its new location.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it was not an unintended omission, my solution gives newly arrived passengers a small walk through the trains wagons. It was not written in the problem description that they shall find their seats in the wagon they entered, after all. And the passengers walking complexity is not contributing to the complexity of the algorithm adversely ;)

The following data type along with the way the data is organized is sufficient.
The Index member is just so we can also keep track of Cells as they move through the data structure upon arrival of new passengers. type Cell could as well simply be an int (the wagon identifier, which is also merely informational).

```
type Cell = { Index : int; Wagon : int }
```

Now, we state our problem in terms of an Array of Lists. The size of the array is 7 (0..6 vacancies in the cells).

We start with an empty train. So all cells are in the list, stored at array index 6 (6 vacancies = empty cell).

Upon arrival of x passengers with x in [1..6], all we have to do is test array[x] to array[6] for being non empty. The first non-empty list contains a cell we want to stuff our passengers in.

Since now the vacancies in that cell is oldVacancies (array index) - x, we add the cell to the list in array[oldVacancies - x].

This algorithm should meet the complexity requirements of the question...at least.

Here a sample implementation in F#:

```
module Trains =
    type Cell = { Index : int; Wagon : int }
    type Problem = List<Cell> []

    let init ncells cellsPerWagon =
        let initCells = 
            [ for i in 0..(ncells-1) do yield { Index = i; Wagon = i % cellsPerWagon } ]
        Array.init 7 (fun i -> if i = 6 then initCells else [] )

    let arrival (nPassengers : int) (problem : Problem) : Problem option =
        let rec findCell (index : int) : (Cell * int) option =
            if index > 6 then None
            else
                match problem.[index] with
                | [] -> findCell (index+1)
                | c::cs -> 
                    problem.[index] <- cs
                    Some(c,index)
        match nPassengers with
        | 0 -> Some(problem)
        | x when x > 6 -> None
        | _ -> 
            let maybeFound = findCell nPassengers
            match maybeFound with
            | Some(cell,vacancies) ->
                problem.[vacancies - nPassengers] <- cell :: problem.[vacancies - nPassengers]
                Some(problem)
            | None -> None
```